# Helm indentation in values file

Tags: terraform, airflow, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-helm

I am deploying the official airflow helm chart https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-airflow/airflow using terraform and I am trying to read a pod template file using the `file` function and use it inside the `values.yaml`

```
resource "helm_release" "airflow" {
  name       = "airflow"
  namespace  = "airflow"
  repository = "https://airflow.apache.org"
  chart      = "airflow"
  version    = "1.11.0"

  values = [
    templatefile("values.yaml", {
      ...
      template_file = file("${path.module}/airflow_templates/common_template.yaml")
    })
  ]
}
```

My main focus is on the `extraConfigMaps` from https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/values.yaml#L349

```
extraConfigMaps:
  airflow-pod-templates-cm:
    data: |-
      test: 'hello'
      common_template.yaml: "${template_file}"
```

however this gives me

```
Error: ---> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 109: could not find expected ':'
```

which I suspect is the wrong indentation, because the content of `common_template.yaml` is printed correctly. I am unable to set the correct indentation though, I tried various versions of templating like `{{ printf "${template_path}" | indent 8 }}`  or `{{ "${template_path}" | indent 8 }}` , but can't get it to work properly. How do I indent this correctly?

Content of the `common_template.yaml` is this file https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/files/pod-template-file.kubernetes-helm-yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually solved it using in the tf file

```
template_file = indent(8, file("${path.module}/airflow_templates/common_template.yaml"))
```

and in the values file

```
extraConfigMaps:
  airflow-pod-templates-cm:
    data: |
      common_template.yaml: |-
        ${template_path}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've - after | for "data", can you try following instead

```
extraConfigMaps:
  airflow-pod-templates-cm:
    data: |
      test: 'hello'
      common_template.yaml: "${template_file}"
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. I am still getting the same error. The content of the file doesn't seem do be indented properly.

Comment: The only difference between `|` and `|-` here is whether the parsed YAML content ends with a newline or not.